# PHP strange result of multiplying by -1

Tags: php, floating-point

```
$res = 0.0 * -1.0;
```

I get float -0

What is this strange behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating point numbers allow have a [signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).

You shouldn't worry, however, as `+0.0 === -0.0` <sup>([demo](http://ideone.com/85OPg))</sup>. (Not that you should use that sort of comparison for floats.)

Answer (score 6):

Because floating-point has [both +0 and -0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).